# why the values passed in a callback are returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here im trying to write a custom each method as in jquery, for that in each function im checking whether the object is array-like or not and if it is array like im running a loop and calling a callback function by sending aruguments in each function. in each function im getting correct values but in call back they are returning as undefined.

```js
var obj = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

var isArrayLike = function(obj){
 if(typeof obj.length === "number"){
  if(obj.length===0){
   return true;   
  }
  else if(obj.length>=0){
   return (obj.length)-1 in obj; 
  }
 }
 return false;
}

function cb(ob,ik){
//here value of ob is returning as 2 and id as undefined
    console.log(ob)
 console.log(ik)
 if(document.getElementById(ik).checked){
   console.log(ik)
 } 
}

function each (obj,cb) {
 if(isArrayLike(obj)){
  for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++){
   var id = obj[i].getAttribute('id');
   cb.call(obj,id)
  }
 }
}

each(obj,cb)
```

Comment: syntax for call function is `fun.call(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])`

Comment: look into https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, to `call()` you are passing `obj` and `id`, the first argument to `call` will be passed as the value of `this` in the callback  and second argument will be passed as the value of first parameter and so on. So in your case `obj` is passed as the value of `this` and the `id` is passed as the value of `ob`, so `ik` has become undefined since there is no value passed to it.

One solution is to use `this` to refer to the current element in the callback, another is to pass the `obj[i]` as the `this` value and as the first parameter.

```
cb.call(obj[i], obj[i], id)
```

---

Since you are passing the dom object itself to the callback, there is no need to pass the id

```js
var obj = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

var isArrayLike = function(obj) {
  if (typeof obj.length === "number") {
    if (obj.length === 0) {
      return true;
    } else if (obj.length >= 0) {
      return (obj.length) - 1 in obj;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

function cb(ob) {
  //here value of ob is returning as 2 and id as undefined
  console.log(ob, this)
  if (ob.checked) {
    snippet.log(ob.id)
  }
}

function each(obj, cb) {
  if (isArrayLike(obj)) {
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
      cb.call(obj[i], obj[i])
    }
  }
}

function testit() {
  each(obj, cb)
}
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="1" />
<input type="checkbox" id="2" />

<button onclick="testit()">Test</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, i got confused with the context and argument, as both are same in this case, so i should have passed obj for 2 times as context and as well as 2nd argument.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) you are calling `Function.prototype.call()` in a wrong way.When calling the `call()` function first parameter is the value of `this` in the calling function. Parameters for the calling function starts from the second parameter in `call()` function.

Here is an example from MDN,

```
var animals = [
  { species: 'Lion', name: 'King' },
  { species: 'Whale', name: 'Fail' }
];

for (var i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    this.print = function() {
      console.log('#' + i + ' ' + this.species
                  + ': ' + this.name);
    }
    this.print();
  }).call(animals[i], i);
}
```

You got undefined because you didn't pass a second parameter to you function with `cb.call(obj,id)`

So passing your parameters as 2nd and 3rd parameters to `call()` function will solve your problem.

```
function each (obj,cb) {
if(isArrayLike(obj)){
    for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++){
        var id = obj[i].getAttribute('id');
        cb.call(obj,obj,id)
    }
}
}
```